# Who exactly was Hagrid expecting in the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, hagrid

In the second Harry Potter movie, Hagrid comes to the door slowly while carrying his crossbow only to see Harry and Ron under the invisibility cloak. Then afterwards he does the same only to reveal Dumbledore and Cornelius Fudge with the late entry of Lucius Malfoy. At first I assumed that it was for Lucius but that doesn't seem likely. Who or what was Hagrid expecting at his door?

Comment: UGHH SO MANY CHOICES T.T

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hagrid had been blamed (wrongly) for opening the chamber 50 years previously. This led to his expulsion from Hogwarts and the snapping of his wand. When the Chamber was reopened, Hagrid knew he would be blamed again and was expecting the Ministry.

Comment: This seems plausible...I keep forgetting that Hagrid was  falsely accused of opening Azkaban,however bludgeoning a member of the ministry with a crossbow does seem a bit... o.o ugh

Comment: @THISISSPAAARRRTTTTAAA Right, when you know the Ministry is going to come to question you answering the door with a crossbow isn't really a good idea. Hagrid isn't exactly known for making good decisions though.

Comment: It's really not clear in the movie who Hagrid is expecting, and reading the book for clarification doesn't help. He merely says to Harry and Ron, "I was expectin' ... never mind" etc. I think the Ministry is a better guess than Dumbledore or Lucius Malfoy. While Hagrid might have held a crossbow on Malfoy, I can't imagine he would have ever done so *knowingly* on Dumbledore.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - I wonder if it's Azkaban really Hagrid fears the most, more than just being questioned by the Ministry ...?

Comment: @aSlytherin Oh, definitely. However, waving a crossbow in their faces the moment you answer the door isn't going to persuade them that you're not a danger to the students and staff at the school (in fact I think it would do quite the opposite). I suppose if Hagrid's going in with the mindset that he's going to be sent to Azkaban regardless then he has nothing to lose, and having a crossbow isn't going to change anything.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist -- All great points. Yes, the crossbow was perhaps not the wisest accessory Hagrid could have chosen. :P

Comment: ... no, I'm a meat popcicle...

Answer (score 9):

By looking the series of events that had occurred before this context,he was probably expecting the monster which had already attacked Mrs.Norris,Justin and Nearly Headless Nick.It might just have been as a part of precaution

Comment: Given that he was a half-breed, a sensible worry.

Comment: The chickens (roosters?) in his yard were also attacked, he might have been ready for another attack.

Answer (score -2):

My friend and I discussed this several days ago and I am happy to see someone has asked this question. Our first theory was that Hagrid was expecting the monster in which attacked other classmates. However, after some thought it seemed unlikely this 'monster' would travel outwit the castle to Hagrid's cottage and additionally to attack Hagrid who (to my knowledge) is not muggle-born or half & half. We concluded our discussion with the theory that he was expecting the people who appear at the door after harry and Ron; Fudge and Dumbledore who are accusing him of the second opening of the chamber of the secrets. When fudge says 'I'm sorry but Hagrid's record is against him' and then continue on to take Hagrid to Azkaban proves our theory.

Comment: Well, Hagrid is kind of half-blood, if that’s what you mean by “half-and-half.” He’s the son of a wizard and a giant. The sort of wizards and witches who care about blood status often have more insulting words for half-giants, though.

Comment: Also, this is more of a Q&A site, so it would be nice if you could clarify the thesis of your answer. Is it that Hagrid was afraid that Fudge would show up to take him in by force?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I hope you stick around. I see you've already got a downvote. This is quite conjectural and could use some meatier supporting material, like quotes or references. Also is it my interpretation, or are you basically supporting the accepted answer? Having said all that, though, (Stackexchange is a little weird, it isn't like a forum, but a Q&A site, so you have to have an original, and ideally well-supported answer, you can't just add some thoughts to the pot, so late answers and posts by new users go into a queue for review) this isn't bad for a 1st post, I agree with you

Answer (score -2):

Its my theory has Hagrid was expecting Malfoy. Using context, Hagrid is nervous when Harry and Ron arrive & is ready for "battle". It obviously isnt the snake he's expecting, he's expecting a person who is likely to blame/scold him for the attacks the same way Tom Riddle did decades prior. In this scene we see Hargrid anxious & showing aggression right? Well Hagrid calms dowm when he answers for Harry & Ron; he calms down when he answers the door for Dumbledoor & the minister, but Hargrid gets UPSET and aggressive when *Malfoy* shows up at his door. He is defensive & clearly treats Malfoy as an unwanted guest. Its safe to say that is was Malfoy (or someone like him) that Hagrid was ready to have a fight with. He likely figured it would only be a matter of time before someone came blaming him for the attacks, so thats what made him paranoid/hostile in the first place. (My theory)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It's fine to disagree with the question (which believes it _isn't_ Lucius), but it's not clear you've sufficiently argued it wasn't someone else.